# developing a system like google directory in sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

i want develop a system in sharepoint 2007 that work similar google directory.
but i don't know how to achieve that. please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint 2007 comes with it's own search and indexing functions, are you trying to avoid using those for some reason, or are you trying to simply change the UI to look more like Google, or what?

Actually trying to scratch build a search feature for SharePoint would be a pretty non-trivial task.